# Trouble passing ArrayList from Java Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

so within this Java servlet, I have an array of file names present within a directory:

```
        String file = "/Library/Tomcat/webapps/HelloServlet/src";
        File f = new File(file);

        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(f.list()));

        request.setAttribute("names", names);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

This part is fine, however, I am stuggling to print the array within the JSP, inside a table:

```
<table class="main" id="tableMain">
<thead>
<th scope="col">File Name</th>
<% 

if (request.getAttribute("names") != null) {
    ArrayList itemsArray = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("names");

    for (int i=0; i < itemsArray.size(); i++) {

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>" + itemsArray.get(i) + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>"); 
        }
    }

%>
</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated, been stuck on this for a while, many thanks!!

Comment: In which way are you struggling? What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Nothing is printing in the table unfortunately

Comment: You should not be using scriptlets in JSP.  That's a 1990s idiom that no one should be using anymore.

Comment: thanks for your 'help'